# What could be the cause of this Chkdsk mid-message deadlock?

Tags: windows, chkdsk

What could cause the following chkdsk result:

```
chkdsk /b /f /v /scan c:

The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
```

This is normal when trying to check the system drive (you're asked to re-schedule it for the next reboot). The message normally continues with

```
checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N) Y
```

but the last line in my case is missing. Chkdsk never prints it and won't respond to user input, so I can't schedule the custom scan. Chkdsk appears to be stuck in a deadlock. It's not waiting on any resources, CPU usage is 0%, memory usage only 920KiB.
Here's a stack trace for the input thread:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2106
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x135e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!KeStallWhileFrozen+0x1feb
ntoskrnl.exe!KeIsAttachedProcess+0x229
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x152f
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xb2
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x6553
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
ifsutil.dll!BLOCK_CACHE::Initialize+0x2fe
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

And here's one for the main thread:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2106
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x135e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlInitializeOplock+0x3d1
ntoskrnl.exe!NtReadFile+0x664
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x6553
ntdll.dll!ZwReadFile+0xa
KERNELBASE.dll!ReadFile+0x78
ulib.dll!KEYBOARD::EnableLineMode+0xc8
ulib.dll!PROGRAM::GetStandardOutput+0x18e
ulib.dll!STREAM::ReadLine+0x13d
ulib.dll!CHKDSK_MESSAGE::IsYesResponse+0x232
ulib.dll!CHKDSK_MESSAGE::IsYesResponse+0xbd
UNTFS.DLL!ChkdskEx+0x61e
chkdsk.exe+0x2c4f
chkdsk.exe+0x3e6c
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Comment: did you try using /x to dismount first?

Comment: This is irrelevant. I want to see this message and press 'Y" to schedule at next boot, as I can't dismount the system drive. Please re-read the question. The problem is that the expected message does not fully appear. Instead, chkdsk becomes unresponsive.

Comment: The question is written as if `c:` is not the system drive, and continues with `but the third line in my case is missing` but it is unclear what is actually meant. (I can guess, but it is not clear)

By using `/x` you can force the message you want, and the reason for asking is to try and narrow down where it goes wrong and remove need for that detection, as of now we don't know if it hangs during the detection of the need to dismount. With more information you get a better chance of getting help.

Comment: The top code div/box. That's what the program outputs. The bottom box. That's what it's supposed to output as well, and does in every example I've found. On one of my servers, it does not. Why. Why does the output simply stop mid-sentence like that, with chkdsk in a deadlock, two threads waiting on eachother. Has anyone seen anything like it?